# Hiding/Showing Elements within Bootstrap Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Coda 2 on Mac
Using HTML, CSS, JS and Bootstrap 3 (via CDN)

Single webpage

Series of links
Placing various form elements in second column.

Goal: On clicking a specific links contained within bootstrap grid
When specific link is clicked, related content should be shown while others are all hidden.

Adapted code from previously answered question that is at fiddle @ YsmVn

Now getting JS Post error. I don't understand JS, but my guess is I need an alternative to .siblings().hide()

My relevant code is

```
<a href="" class="one">One</a>
<a href="" class="two">Two</a>
<a href="" class="three">Three</a>
<a href="" class="four">Four</a><br /><br />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="one">One</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <div id="two">Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="three">Three</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="four">Four</div><br/><br/>
        </div>
</div>
```

and the Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


      // Show chosen div, and hide all others
    $("a").click(function (e) 
    {
            e.preventDefault();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For the record, the *direct* link to the fiddle you mentioned is this:
   http://jsfiddle.net/YsmVn/
2. Not knowing what you truly aim to do, just wondering if you have 
   considered using the bootstrap tabs or collapse components? As it is 
   now, it seems like you are going down the road of re-inventing the wheel.

   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
3. Here is a bit of an alternate version of the code you posted, 
   with a working sample. In this sample, the divs are all initially 
   set to display, but that obviously can be changed.

   **http://jsbin.com/decobeba/1/edit?html,css,output**

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Show chosen div, and hide all others
    $("#my-nav a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#my-nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.my-section').hide();
        var sectionActive = $(this).data('section');
        $('#' + sectionActive).show();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-nav">
   <a href="#" data-section="one">One</a>
   <a href="#" data-section="two">Two</a>
   <a href="#" data-section="three">Three</a>
   <a href="#" data-section="four">Four</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="one" class="my-section">One</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <div id="two" class="my-section">Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="three" class="my-section">Three</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="four" class="my-section">Four</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```